# How can I get FreeNAS to respond to libvirt shutdown requests

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, electrical-power, truenas

I have a KVM VM of FreeNAS 0.7.1 Shere (revision 5127) running on Ubuntu Server 10.04 and I'm unable to convince the VM to shutdown from the host

```
virsh shutdown freenas
```

I would expect this to send some ACPI? trigger to the VM and FreeNAS then do what it's told.

I'm not a FreeBSD fundi so I don't really know what packages or processes to poke to get this running. I have tried to convince powerd to run, but the VM cpus don't have the required freq entry

Sysctl HW

```
$ sysctl hw
hw.machine: amd64
hw.model: QEMU Virtual CPU version 0.12.3
hw.ncpu: 1
hw.byteorder: 1234
hw.physmem: 523116544
hw.usermem: 463806464
hw.pagesize: 4096
hw.floatingpoint: 1
hw.machine_arch: amd64
hw.realmem: 536850432
hw.aac.iosize_max: 65536
hw.amr.force_sg32: 0
hw.an.an_cache_iponly: 1
hw.an.an_cache_mcastonly: 0
hw.an.an_cache_mode: dbm
hw.an.an_dump: off
hw.ata.to: 15
hw.ata.wc: 1
hw.ata.atapi_dma: 1
hw.ata.ata_dma_check_80pin: 1
hw.ata.ata_dma: 1
hw.ath.txbuf: 200
hw.ath.rxbuf: 40
hw.ath.regdomain: 0
hw.ath.countrycode: 0
hw.ath.xchanmode: 1
hw.ath.outdoor: 1
hw.ath.calibrate: 30
hw.ath.hal.swba_backoff: 0
hw.ath.hal.sw_brt: 10
hw.ath.hal.dma_brt: 2
hw.bce.msi_enable: 1
hw.bce.tso_enable: 1
hw.bge.allow_asf: 0
hw.cardbus.cis_debug: 0
hw.cardbus.debug: 0
hw.cs.recv_delay: 570
hw.cs.ignore_checksum_failure: 0
hw.cs.debug: 0
hw.cxgb.snd_queue_len: 50
hw.cxgb.use_16k_clusters: 1
hw.cxgb.force_fw_update: 0
hw.cxgb.singleq: 0
hw.cxgb.ofld_disable: 0
hw.cxgb.msi_allowed: 2
hw.cxgb.txq_mr_size: 1024
hw.cxgb.sleep_ticks: 1
hw.cxgb.tx_coalesce: 0
hw.firewire.hold_count: 3
hw.firewire.try_bmr: 1
hw.firewire.fwmem.speed: 2
hw.firewire.fwmem.eui64_lo: 0
hw.firewire.fwmem.eui64_hi: 0
hw.firewire.phydma_enable: 1
hw.firewire.nocyclemaster: 0
hw.firewire.fwe.rx_queue_len: 128
hw.firewire.fwe.tx_speed: 2
hw.firewire.fwe.stream_ch: 1
hw.firewire.fwip.rx_queue_len: 128
hw.firewire.sbp.tags: 0
hw.firewire.sbp.use_doorbell: 0
hw.firewire.sbp.scan_delay: 500
hw.firewire.sbp.login_delay: 1000
hw.firewire.sbp.exclusive_login: 1
hw.firewire.sbp.max_speed: -1
hw.firewire.sbp.auto_login: 1
hw.mfi.max_cmds: 128
hw.mfi.event_class: 0
hw.mfi.event_locale: 65535
hw.pccard.cis_debug: 0
hw.pccard.debug: 0
hw.cbb.debug: 0
hw.cbb.start_32_io: 4096
hw.cbb.start_16_io: 256
hw.cbb.start_memory: 2281701376
hw.pcic.pd6722_vsense: 1
hw.pcic.intr_mask: 57016
hw.pci.honor_msi_blacklist: 1
hw.pci.enable_msix: 1
hw.pci.enable_msi: 1
hw.pci.do_power_resume: 1
hw.pci.do_power_nodriver: 0
hw.pci.enable_io_modes: 1
hw.pci.host_mem_start: 2147483648
hw.syscons.kbd_debug: 1
hw.syscons.kbd_reboot: 1
hw.syscons.bell: 1
hw.syscons.saver.keybonly: 1
hw.syscons.sc_no_suspend_vtswitch: 0
hw.usb.uplcom.interval: 100
hw.usb.uvscom.interval: 100
hw.usb.uvscom.opktsize: 8
hw.wi.debug: 0
hw.wi.txerate: 0
hw.xe.debug: 0
hw.intr_storm_threshold: 1000
hw.availpages: 127714
hw.bus.devctl_disable: 0
hw.ste.rxsyncs: 0
hw.busdma.total_bpages: 32
hw.busdma.zone0.total_bpages: 32
hw.busdma.zone0.free_bpages: 32
hw.busdma.zone0.reserved_bpages: 0
hw.busdma.zone0.active_bpages: 0
hw.busdma.zone0.total_bounced: 0
hw.busdma.zone0.total_deferred: 0
hw.busdma.zone0.lowaddr: 0xffffffff
hw.busdma.zone0.alignment: 2
hw.busdma.zone0.boundary: 65536
hw.clockrate: 2808
hw.instruction_sse: 1
hw.apic.enable_extint: 0
hw.kbd.keymap_restrict_change: 0
hw.acpi.supported_sleep_state: S3 S4 S5
hw.acpi.power_button_state: S5
hw.acpi.sleep_button_state: S3
hw.acpi.lid_switch_state: NONE
hw.acpi.standby_state: S1
hw.acpi.suspend_state: S3
hw.acpi.sleep_delay: 1
hw.acpi.s4bios: 0
hw.acpi.verbose: 0
hw.acpi.disable_on_reboot: 0
hw.acpi.handle_reboot: 0
hw.acpi.cpu.cx_lowest: C1
```

Processes

```
$ ps ax
  PID  TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
    0  ??  DLs    0:00.00 [swapper]
    1  ??  ILs    0:00.00 /sbin/init --
    2  ??  DL     0:00.08 [g_event]
    3  ??  DL     0:00.29 [g_up]
    4  ??  DL     0:00.33 [g_down]
    5  ??  DL     0:00.00 [crypto]
    6  ??  DL     0:00.00 [crypto returns]
    7  ??  DL     0:00.00 [xpt_thrd]
    8  ??  DL     0:00.00 [kqueue taskq]
    9  ??  DL     0:00.00 [acpi_task_0]
   10  ??  RL    34:12.42 [idle: cpu0]
   11  ??  WL     0:01.13 [swi4: clock sio]
   12  ??  WL     0:00.00 [swi3: vm]
   13  ??  WL     0:00.00 [swi1: net]
   14  ??  DL     0:00.04 [yarrow]
   15  ??  WL     0:00.00 [swi6: task queue]
   16  ??  WL     0:00.00 [swi2: cambio]
   17  ??  DL     0:00.00 [acpi_task_1]
   18  ??  DL     0:00.00 [acpi_task_2]
   19  ??  WL     0:00.00 [swi5: +]
   20  ??  DL     0:00.01 [thread taskq]
   21  ??  WL     0:00.00 [swi6: Giant taskq]
   22  ??  WL     0:00.00 [irq9: acpi0]
   23  ??  WL     0:00.09 [irq14: ata0]
   24  ??  WL     0:00.11 [irq15: ata1]
   25  ??  WL     0:00.57 [irq11: ed0 uhci0]
   26  ??  DL     0:00.00 [usb0]
   27  ??  DL     0:00.00 [usbtask-hc]
   28  ??  DL     0:00.00 [usbtask-dr]
   29  ??  WL     0:00.01 [irq1: atkbd0]
   30  ??  WL     0:00.00 [swi0: sio]
   31  ??  DL     0:00.00 [sctp_iterator]
   32  ??  DL     0:00.00 [pagedaemon]
   33  ??  DL     0:00.00 [vmdaemon]
   34  ??  DL     0:00.00 [idlepoll]
   35  ??  DL     0:00.00 [pagezero]
   36  ??  DL     0:00.01 [bufdaemon]
   37  ??  DL     0:00.00 [vnlru]
   38  ??  DL     0:00.14 [syncer]
   39  ??  DL     0:00.01 [softdepflush]
 1221  ??  Is     0:00.00 /sbin/devd
 1289  ??  Is     0:00.01 /usr/sbin/syslogd -ss -f /var/etc/syslog.conf
 1608  ??  Is     0:00.00 /usr/sbin/cron -s
 1692  ??  Ss     0:00.03 /usr/local/sbin/mDNSResponderPosix -b -f /var/etc/mdn
 1730  ??  S      0:00.43 /usr/local/sbin/lighttpd -f /var/etc/lighttpd.conf -m
 1882  ??  DL     0:00.00 [system_taskq]
 1883  ??  DL     0:00.00 [arc_reclaim_thread]
 4139  ??  S      0:00.03 /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/www/exec.php
 4144  ??  S      0:00.00 sh -c ps ax
 4145  ??  R      0:00.00 ps ax
 1816  v0  Is     0:00.01 login [pam] (login)
 1818  v0  I+     0:00.03 -tcsh (csh)
 1817  v1  Is+    0:00.00 /usr/libexec/getty Pc ttyv1
 1402 con- I      0:00.00 /usr/local/sbin/afpd -F /var/etc/afpd.conf
 1404 con- S      0:00.00 /usr/local/sbin/cnid_metad
 1682 con- I      0:02.78 /usr/local/sbin/mt-daapd -m -c /var/etc/mt-daapd.conf
 1789 con- S      0:00.18 /usr/local/bin/fuppesd --config-dir /var/etc --config
```

Libvert snippet

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>freenas</name>
  <uuid>********-****-****-****-************</uuid>
  <memory>524288</memory>
  <currentMemory>524288</currentMemory>
  <vcpu>1</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-0.12'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
```

Is this possible? Ideally I'd like to be able to stop the host without having to manually deal with shutting down the VM.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've found to get this working is to pass the -no-kvm-irqchip parameter to kvm. The easiest way to do this in libvirt is to create a wrapper script (eg /usr/local/bin/kvmbsd)

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/kvm "$@" -no-kvm-irqchip
```

And change the emulator line in your libvirt configuration to point to the wrapper script.

`/usr/local/bin/kvmbsd`

This allows me to cleanly shutdown (but not reboot - this doesn't appear to be implemented in libvirt/kvm yet) my freebsd based vms.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the VM has ACPI enabled, that's what a clean shutdown does - send an ACPI call.
There are other ways however, like scripting a shutdown command through ssh, using monitorCommand sendKey to send a keypress designed to initiate a shutdown, running a "destroy" command (essentially a plug pull) etc.

Comment: If you look at the libvirt snippet, you can see the <acpi/> feature...

Comment: does the OS have ACPI enabled though?